# Is the integral $\int e^{ax + b/x}dx$ solvable?

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve this integral:

$$\int_0^\infty  e^{ax + b/x}dx,$$

where $a$ and $b$ are negative constants.

Does anyone know whether this is possible and how I might go about doing this?

Thanks a lot!

Here's an example:

[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mffa8.png)

Comment: The special case $\int \exp(1/x) dx$ does not converge.

Comment: Neither $\int_0^{\infty}e^xdx$

Comment: @popi $a = 1$ is not a negative constant.

Comment: OP has just edited !!

Comment: Ah, fair enough!

Answer (score 2):

It can be writen in terms of Modified Bessel function of second kind $K_v(x)$.

Rewrite $a=-\alpha^2$ and $b=-\beta^2$ with $\alpha,\beta\geq0$.

$$\int_0^\infty e^{ax+\frac{b}{x}}dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha\beta\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}x+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\frac{1}{x}\right)}dx$$

Performig change $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}x=e^y$ your integral reads

$$\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\alpha\beta\,\cosh y}e^y\,dy=\frac{2\,\beta}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2\alpha\beta\,\cosh y}\cosh y\,dy$$

Taking account the integral representation of $K_v(x)$ (see [integral representation $K_v(x)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E9))

$$\boxed{\int_0^\infty e^{ax+\frac{b}{x}}dx=\frac{2\,\beta}{\alpha}K_1(2\alpha\beta)=2\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}K_1(2\sqrt{a\,b})}$$

Comment: Excellent. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case with $a = 0, b = 1$. The function $\exp(1/x) > 1$ for $x>0$. Therefore,

$$\int_0^\infty \exp(1/x) dx \geq \int_0^\infty 1 dx = \infty$$

Comment: Thank you! I was going to add, if we know that a and b are negative can we work with it?